# make install throwing .ptk related error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, vtk

I am trying to install vtk and use it along with python on my ubuntu machine. I installed VTK and i was able to configure and generate, then I did a 'sudo make install', this is giving me the following error, I am not sure which path has to be set and how to make python read .pth files from that folder, I am new to both VTK and Python, so any advice would be of great help.

Thanks,
Shripad D

make install error:

Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/opt/bitnami/python/bin/.python2.7.bin -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

```
'/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/svn-python::/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/svn-python::'
```

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

- You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files
- You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)
- You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using BitNami (I think that you are using the BitNami Django Stack). Can you trying to load the BitNami environment and then run the commands?

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/use_djangostack
cd /opt/bitnami
. scripts/setenv.sh
```

In the last command notice the space between the dot and the script.

Comment: Thanks kaysa, I noticed that I have django in the /opt/bitnami/apps/django directory. I could not run use_djangostack from /opt/bitnami/ so I tried running from /opt/bitnami/apps/django but the file is nowhere to be found. can you tell me what else has to be done.

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine or an Amazon Cloud Image? In that case, just login as root, go to the /opt/bitnami directory and load the environment with `. scripts/setenv.sh`